# synchronizing alsa volume to all pulse audio sinks

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, alsamixer

I control my computer's audio using key bindings linking XF86 audio key presses to amixer commands. This works well, unless I am listening through a non-alsa sink such as bluetooth-connected headphones. In this case, the volume is controlled through pulse audio and my key bindings no longer work. Is there a simple way to reflect changes in alsa volume to all sinks known by pulse audio (e.g., such that a -5% change in the master alsa volume would also be applied to all pulse audio sinks)?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the simplest way is to change your key bindings, and instead of `amixer` commands, issue `pactl` or `pacmd` commands. Wrapped in a script that iterates over all sinks.

Pulseaudio does track the ALSA mixer setting, but only for the sink which is connected to the ALSA hardware, and I don't see an easy way to change this.